# Nice remote apache log viewer

Tags: apache, browser, logging, viewer

I have a server with 10+ virtual domains (most running Mediawiki). I'd like to be able to watch their traffic remotely with something nicer than tail -f . I could cobble something together, but was wondering if something super-deluxe already exists that involves a minimum of hacking and support. This is mostly to understand what's going on, not so much for security (though it could serve that role too). It must:

- be able to deal with vhost log files
- be able to handle updates every 10 seconds or so
- Be free/open source

The nice to haves are:

- Browser based display (supported by a web app/daemon on the server)
- Support filters (bots, etc)
- Features like counters for pages, with click to view history
- Show a nice graphical display of a geographic map, timeline, etc
- Identify individual browsers
- Show link relationships (coming from remote site, to page, to another page)
- Be able to identify logfile patterns (editing or creating a page)

I run Debian on the server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/product).
I'm not sure if it supports real time (~10 second) updates but there are a ton of features and it's pretty easy to get set up.

The free version has some limitations but there is also an enterprise version.

Comment: Thanks Rich, I didn't realize Splunk (which has an awful name IMO) has an open source version. Will investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Logstash is the current answer. (=

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the volume, [Papertrail](https://papertrailapp.com/plans) could be free for you. It is the closest thing to a `tail -f` and is searchable, archivable and also sends alerts based on custom criteria.